# Font is spread across several files

Tags: ios, fonts, hebrew, android-fonts

I want to use the Droid font in my iOS application, which currently mainly supports Hebrew. The Droid font package contains several files, two of which are `DroidSans.ttf` and `DroidHebrewSans.ttf`.

The Hebrew font contains Hebrew glyphs, but nothing more (in particular, no digits). The plain font contains the rest, as well as many other languages.

Both fonts are embedded in my application, and I can access them both using `[UIFont fontWithName:size:]`. The problem is that if I load one font, I don't get Hebrew, and if I load the other, I don't get digits and punctuation.

To stress out - I'm interested in assigning an `NSString` to a `UILabel`'s text property, and be done with it. Scanning the string and applying attributes according to code-page is not really a solution.

Am I missing something? Am I supposed to somehow merge the fonts? Is there an already-merged font which I'm missing?

**EDIT:** I've noticed the `fallback_fonts.xml` and `system_fonts.xml` files in the Android fonts directory. These define the various fonts and priorities to be used when drawing a glyph. Is there something similar for iOS ?